# How to place SplitContainerControl's splitter at a percentual position?

Tags: winforms, devexpress, splitter

Is there a way to place SplitContainerControl's splitter at a percentual position of the control size, that keeps even if its container is resized? Or, on the other hand, set the size of the panels to a percentual value?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the [SplitContainerControl.FixedPanel](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraEditorsSplitContainerControl_FixedPaneltopic) property is set to the `SplitFixedPanel.None` value, the panels' widths (or heights) are changed proportionally when the container is being resized.
Thus, just do not use fixed panels within SplitContainerControl:

```
splitContainerControl1.FixedPanel = DevExpress.XtraEditors.SplitFixedPanel.None;
splitContainerControl1.SplitterPosition = splitContainerControl1.Width / 3;
```

Answer (score 2):

Override `Control.OnLayout` and set `SplitContainerControl.SplitterPosition` based on the percentage.

Answer (score 1):

Solution 1:
Refer: DevExpress : [SplitContainerControl - Defaulting splitter position to 50%](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q454839)

To adjust the splitter position, simply set the [SplitContainerControl.SplitterPosition](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraEditorsSplitContainerControl_SplitterPositiontopic) property to a half size of a control. For example, if you wish to set the splitter position of the vertical SplitContainerControl, use the following code snippet:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    splitContainerControl1.SplitterPosition = splitContainerControl1.Height / 2; 
}
```

Solution 2:

> If there is no fixed panel, the [SplitterPosition](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraEditorsSplitContainerControl_SplitterPositiontopic) property
>   specifies the splitter's location from the container's left or top
>   edge (according to the [Horizontal](http://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraEditorsSplitContainerControl_Horizontaltopic.aspx) property).
>
> If the FixedPanel property is set to the [SplitFixedPanel.None](http://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraEditorsSplitFixedPanelEnumtopic.aspx)
>   value, the panels' widths (or heights) are changed proportionally when
>   the container is being resized.

To change splitter position on the Form.Shown or Form.SizeChanged event handler.
//First set the FixedPanel property

```
splitContainerControl1.FixedPanel = DevExpress.XtraEditors.SplitFixedPanel.None;
```

then you can use the Parnet control's Control.ClientSizeChanged Event as below:

```
private void ParentControl_ClientSizeChanged(Object sender, EventArgs e) 
{

   splitContainerControl1.SplitterPosition = splitContainerControl1.Width / 2;
   or
   splitContainerControl1.SplitterPosition = ParentControl.Width / 2;   

}
```